# C# to R - HTTP GET

Tags: c#, r, httr

I have a sample code from a rather pooly documented API, but it's in C# and I'm not very familiar with the syntax.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class SimpleRestClient
{
    public void FetchANotice()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = CreateBasicHeader("USER", "PASS");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
        var task = client.GetStreamAsync("http://XYZ/Doffin/notice/2013-1234567");
        task.Wait();
        using (var stream = task.Result)
        {
            var xdoc = XDocument.Load(stream);

            // XML document fetched, do something with it
            Console.Out.WriteLine(xdoc);
        }
    }

    private static AuthenticationHeaderValue CreateBasicHeader(string username, string password)
    {
        var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username + ":" + password);
        return new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
    }
}
```

What I would like is a GET request using R, in particular HTTR. This is my best try so far:

```
dat <- httr::VERB(
  verb = "GET", url = "https://epsapiv3-doffin.test.eu-supply.com",
  httr::add_headers(
    Accept = "application/json",
    Content-Type = "application/json",
    Authorization = "Basic {base64_encode(Username:Password)}"
  )
)
```

Comment: Uh.... `application/json` seems wrong given your C# code.

Comment: And note that `Content-*` headers describe the request BODY.

Comment: application/xml or application/json are optional - I want it as a json object, it's just that they've used xml in the example.

Comment: I see. I recommend comparing your request with a tool like Telerik's Fiddler to see what's wrong (run the C# request with it running, confirm it succeeds, run the R request with it running, check the difference between the two). I'd definitely remove the `Content-Type` header since there is no content, but as for your R code I can't really help because I'm not an R programmer.

Comment: It's ok, I figured it out in the end.